# Read from an external program/console

Tags: c#, console, output, streamreader

I have a problem, I need to execute a console program and I have to show the output information of that console on my program. I have a string variable called "result" that have to storage that information, but is always null and I don't know why. Can anyone help me? I put the code below:

```
 Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "python";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Users\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx_\xxx yyy\zzz.py " + path;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.Start();

            StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
            p.WaitForExit();
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

            textBox1.Text = result;
```

On the console, I recieve 8382 JGK, for example, but my result variable is always "".

Comment: You may have a sync problem. Can you add a thread sleep after you start the 1st process? As you are using different processes you are not sure the 1st will be done, when you are trying to read the output from it.

Comment: Yes, I can, but how much time? Thread.sleep(5000), for example?

Comment: ReadToEnd reads all characters from the current position to the end of the stream, so there's a chance you're at the last position before you start reading.

Comment: I don't know. Do you have an idea how long does your process take to execute?

Comment: @Gnqz i put a sleep of 8 seconds, it takes 4 seconds, and I still recieve ""

Comment: @Vegz so... how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding Console.WriteLine(result); before the p.WaitForExit();

Comment: it doesn't work @Gnqz , any more ideas? :(

Comment: Did you try it with a debugger to see what happens? Can you tell me what you get from string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

Comment: I recieve result = "" even with p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); or with string result = sr.ReadToEnd(); , any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
p.WaitForExit();
char[] result = new char[p.Length]; //or sr.BaseStream.Length
sr.Read(result,0,(int)p.Length); // again or sr.BaseStream.Length
```

And see if result array contains anything.

Comment: it gives me an exception when char[] result = new char[sr.BaseStream.Length];  "the sequence is not compatible with the search"

Comment: Yeah, my bad, sorry. Couldn't test it before. Try `char[] result = new char[128];` (Tbh i don't know if there's a way to get length you need) and then `sr.Read(result, 0, result.Length);` and see if there's any result (it gave 128 times '\0' when using Gimp :P

Comment: it gave me 128 '\0' , not the property result that I have if I use the console program.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to try @Gnqz `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it! The problem was on the file's path. I have to put it on the same folder as the ".py" file and it works fine. I add the correct piece of code:

```
 string python = @"C:\xxx\python.exe";
        string myPythonApp = "program.py";
        string x = @"file.jpg";

        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + x;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.Start();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();
        textBox1.Text = myString;
```